# Вставка в плеер видео с другого сайта

Tags: php, javascript, алгоритм, seo

На некоторых сайтах можно увидеть как в плеер вставляют ссылки вида

`http://site.net/tubes/video.php?v=param`

где `param`  это `base64` кодированные данные о видео с другого сайта. В консоле видно, что видео отдается скриптом с другого сайта. Для каких целей так делают? Как `php` скриптом отдать в плеер видео с другого сайта не закачивая его(к себе на сервер)?

Comment: Скиньте ссылку, про какой конкретно Вы случай говорите. Причин может быть несколько и вариантов решения Вашей задачи то же;)

Comment: @Geri4 Не хотелось бы ссылки давать- вдруг это прием из серого SEO;) Какие могут быть случаи использования таких ссылок? Подскажите хотя бы вторую часть, про то, как php скриптом отдать видео в плеер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в комментарии пытались от меня добиться чего то, я до конца все не понял, какой именно случай вас интересует, по этому рассказываю что то:
***Base64 обычно используют для обмена бинарниками(например файлами), но можно использовать и иначе=)
**Я сделаю уклон именно на это "Как php скриптом отдать в плеер видео с другого сайта не закачивая его" и при этом за уши притянуть base64
1. Я подготовился и сделал вот такую строчку "aHR0cHM6Ly92by5mb2Q0LmNvbS92LzI1YzE3ZDZlYjIvdjYwMC5tcDQ=" по сути это ссылка на видео в base64.
2."http://site.net/tubes/video.php?v=aHR0cHM6Ly92by5mb2Q0LmNvbS92LzI1YzE3ZDZlYjIvdjYwMC5tcDQ"  это теперь наш урл
3.Написал код video.php

```
header( 'Location: '.base64_decode($_GET['v']) );
```

4.Готово "mission complete"
PS.Это решение нужно может для того чтобы скрыть урл с другого сайта от посторонних людей, желание что бы видео мелькало везде с урлом "site.net" но при этом видео не хранить... На самом деле можно не именно base64 использовать для шифрования а что то другое... Так же возможно в вашем случае передавался плейлист в base64 в котором находились ссылки на видео(что было бы более допустимо), может был токен своеобразный и сайту нужно было решать что за урл отдавать...

Comment: То что нужно- благодарю.